Build separate artifacts for child modules in multi-module Maven project
I was wondering what the best practices are on creating separate artifacts for child modules in a multi-module Maven Spring Boot project. So let's say you have one project (operators), one root pom.xml and two child modules. Kafka-operator and proxy-sql-operator should create their own artifacts, they also trigger there own pipeline in Jenkins. We need separate version for it without the need to have two repositories.
Here is an overview of the concept.

I want to control the versions of both modules in the parent pom.xml
Current config in root pom.xml
<parent>
    <groupId>be.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1</version>
</parent>

<groupId>be.example</groupId>
<artifactId>operators</artifactId>
<version>${revision}</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>

<properties>
    <revision>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</revision>

    <kafka-operator.version>0.0.3-SNAPSHOT</kafka-operator.version>
    <proxysql-operator.version>0.0.2-SNAPSHOT</proxysql-operator.version>
</properties>

I expected I could do something like this to use those versions in the child modules.
pom of kafka-operator:
<parent>
    <groupId>be.example.operators</groupId>
    <artifactId>operators</artifactId>
    <version>${revision}</version>
</parent>


<artifactId>kafka-operator</artifactId>
<version>${kafka-operator.version}</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>

<modules>
    <module>kafka-operator-core</module>
    <module>kafka-operator-adapter</module>
</modules>

And in module kafka-operator-core I would do something like this:
<parent>
    <groupId>be.example.operators</groupId>
    <artifactId>kafka-operator</artifactId>
    <version>${kafka-operator.version}</version>
</parent>

<artifactId>kafka-operator-core</artifactId>

But in module kafka-operator-core, Maven complains that the version is incorrect and that I can't use the version defined in the root pom.xml. The same setup applies to the proxysql-operator and its child modules
How can I achieve this?

You're mostly there, but you need to use the Flatten Maven Plugin. See @FrVaBe's answer here.
Add this plugin to your parent pom:
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
  <artifactId>flatten-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.6.0</version>
  <configuration>
    <updatePomFile>true</updatePomFile>
  </configuration>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>flatten</id>
      <phase>process-resources</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>flatten</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>

I'd also suggest moving your definition of ${kafka-operator.version} down to pom of 'kafka-operator' unless you use that version in the sibling pom 'proxysql-operator'.
